# creating page.php file in wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my internship, they've asked me to create a wordpress theme from a static free website template from the internet. I'm an absolute beginner and tried to follow the steps they gave but I'm currently stuck. I don't really know how to include or connect the other html pages  from the site (except from index.html) using the page.php file.
how do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can add the pages from the WordPress dashboard menu section

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

ii) You can create a page template in WordPress(page.php)

Reference: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/
           https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Please use any one option from the above as per your requirements

Comment: thank you very much. i will get to it and post the end result.